# Circle geometry sketching and proving

Tags: circles, angle, quadrilateral

Let K and L be circles with centres O and P, respectively, each of which is exterior to the other circle. Suppose K and L intersect at points A and D, and that the diameter AOB of K intersects L at a second point C lying between A and O. Extend line segment BD to meet L at a second point E.

(a) Prove that AE is a diameter of L.
(b) Prove that OCPD is a cyclic quadrilateral.

I have tried to join A and D and assumed it is perpendicular to line BE. Also I have tried to use subtended angle, but I am stuck now since I am getting the same formula over and over. Also I know that I should be using Thales' theorem but I am not sure how to start.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what the OP's asking!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

First things first: by symmetry, $AD\perp OP$.
$B$ is the antipode of $A$ and $D$ is the symmetric of $A$ wrt the $OP$ line, so $BE\parallel OP\perp AD$.
This implies $\widehat{ADE}=90^\circ$, so $AE$ is a diameter of the second circle.

If $C$ is external to $AB$ (i.e. if $\widehat{BAE}$ is obtuse, like in the above diagram) $\widehat{OPD}=\frac{1}{2}\widehat{APD}=\widehat{ACD}=\widehat{OCD}$. This gives that $OCPD$ is cyclic.

In any case the circumcircle of $OPD$ is the nine point circle of $ABE$, since it goes through the midpoints $P,O$ and the projection of $A$ on $BE$. In particular it has to go through the projection of $E$ on $AB$, which is $C$ since $\widehat{ECA}=\widehat{EDA}=90^\circ$.

Comment: The question says point C is lying between A and O.

Comment: @ACB: but it also says that $O$ and $P$ are external to $L$ and $K$, so I assumed a typo and considered $A$ lying between $O$ and $C$, since I cannot see how $L$ can meet the $OA$ segment at any other point that $A$.

Comment: @ACB: Oh well, now I see. Not a big issue, since with minor adjustements this works also in OP's configuration. I added an alternative proof that works in both cases.

Comment: [+1] for the idea of Euler circle (and for the connection between Ptolemy's inequality and triangle inequality using inversion I didn't know).